Не работает обработчик событий @router.callback_query
В проекте для телеграм-бота я всё импортировал как надо, создал роутер и тд. Но при нажатии на инлайн-клавиатуру ras не вызывается событие @router.callback_query, которое вызывается при нажатии на клавишу "ИСП". Другие клавиши не назначены, поэтому невозможно судить о работоспособности этого куска кода по действительным примерам.
@router.message(F.text == 'Расписание')
async def ras(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите категорию товара', reply_markup=kb.ras)

@router.callback_query(F.date == 'ISP')
async def ISP(callback_query: CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.answer('Ввывывыв')

ras = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='ИСП',callback_data='ISP')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='ПД',callback_data='PD')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='МНЭЭ',callback_data='MN')]])


Ну, во-первых, у вас очень странный конструктор клавиатуры, сделайте его нормальным, например так:
def ras_kb():
    kb = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    kb.button(text="ИСП", callback_data='ISP')
    kb.button(text="ПД", callback_data='PD')
    kb.button(text="МНЭЭ", callback_data='MN')
    kb.adjust(1)
    return kb.as_markup()

далее ее уже можете использовать:
@router.message(F.text == 'Расписание')
async def ras(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите категорию товара', reply_markup=ras_kb())

ну и у вас еще ошибка далее по коду. Вместо F.date должно быть F.data. Итоговый минимальный код будет таким:
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder

def ras_kb():
    kb = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    kb.button(text="ИСП", callback_data='ISP')
    kb.button(text="ПД", callback_data='PD')
    kb.button(text="МНЭЭ", callback_data='MN')
    kb.adjust(1)
    return kb.as_markup()


@router.message(F.text == 'Расписание')
async def ras(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите категорию товара', reply_markup=ras_kb())


@router.callback_query(F.data == 'ISP')
async def ISP(callback_query: CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.answer('Ввывывыв')


File "C:\Users\galus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 49, in call
return await handler(event, data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
now there is such a mistake

@Sokol это не полный текст ошибки. У вас проблема в другом участке кода, потому что код, который я вам написал - рабочий на 100%

у меня проблема в том, что у меня все в разных папках, а не одним кодом

@Sokol проблема решилась? Если да, то можете принять мой ответ в качестве решения, нажав слева от него соответствующую кнопку
